# How to copy via wild card in linux/bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scp, cp

Here is what I am trying to do - assume a source directory:

```
/xyz/2/file.txt
/xyz/2/crapfile.txt
/xyz/3/file.txt
/xyz/3/crapfile.txt
```

and I want to copy file.txt into the following directory:

```
/z/2
/z/3
```

I like to do something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
cp -r /xyz/*/file.txt /z/*/
```

to avoid copying things separately - which I can do with the following:

```
cp -r /xyz/2/file.txt /z/2/
cp -r /xyz/3/file.txt /z/3/
```

Comment: is 2 and 3 the only folders under xyz/ ? also, are you limited to cp .. or you can just use "rsync" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command copies from `xyz` to `z` excluding all files named `crapfile.txt`:

```
rsync -a --exclude=crapfile.txt xyz/ z
```

With the `-v` (verbose) option, we can see its work in progress:

```
$ rsync -va --exclude=crapfile.txt xyz/ z
sending incremental file list
./
2/
2/file.txt
3/
3/file.txt
```

As you can see, `file.txt` was copied but `crapfile.txt` was skipped.

`rsync` is a very powerful utility with many many options.  For more info, see `man rsync` or any of the [`rsync` tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+tutorial) on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop with an `ls`:

```
for I in `ls /xyz`; do mkdir /z/$I; cp -r /xyz/$I/file.txt /z/$I/ ; done
```

(Or if /z/2 and /z/3 is already existing skip `mkdir`!)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a wild card, you could do something similar to:

```
for x in $(ls /xyz) 
do
mkdir /z/$x
cp /xyz/$x/file.txt /z/$x/
done
```

If the folders under z do not already exist, otherwise remove the mkdir line above

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the the question , the below should do it:

```
[za]$ cp -rv xyz/{dir_1/,dir_2}/*  target_dir/
`xyz/dir_1//file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file3_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_1//file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file4_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/file1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/file2.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/file3.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/file4.txt'

[za]$ cp -rv xyz/{dir_1/,dir_2}/*.txt  target_dir/
`xyz/dir_1//file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file3_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_1//file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file4_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/file1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/file2.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/file3.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/file4.txt'



other ways depending on what you are trying to achive. 

1)
[za temp_dir]$ cp -rv xyz/* target_dir/
`xyz/dir_1' -> `target_dir/dir_1'
`xyz/dir_1/file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_1/file3_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_1/file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_1/file4_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2' -> `target_dir/dir_2'
`xyz/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_2/file1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_2/file2.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_2/file3.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/dir_2/file4.txt'

2)
[za temp_dir]$ for x in $(find . -type f) ; do cp -v $x target_dir/ ; done 
`./target_dir/dir_1/file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file3_dir1.txt'
`./target_dir/dir_1/file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file4_dir1.txt'
`./target_dir/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/file1.txt'
`./target_dir/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/file2.txt'
`./target_dir/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/file3.txt'
`./target_dir/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/file4.txt'
`./xyz/dir_1/file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file3_dir1.txt'
`./xyz/dir_1/file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file4_dir1.txt'
`./xyz/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/file1.txt'
`./xyz/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/file2.txt'
`./xyz/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/file3.txt'
`./xyz/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/file4.txt'


3)      
[za temp_dir]$ rsync -rav xyz/* target_dir/
sending incremental file list
dir_1/
dir_1/file3_dir1.txt
dir_1/file4_dir1.txt
dir_2/
dir_2/file1.txt
dir_2/file2.txt
dir_2/file3.txt
dir_2/file4.txt

sent 414 bytes  received 134 bytes  1096.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
[za temp_dir]$ 


4)
[za]$  find xyz/ | while read ; do cp -v $REPLY target_dir/ ; done 
cp: omitting directory `xyz/'
cp: omitting directory `xyz/dir_1'
`xyz/dir_1/file3_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file3_dir1.txt'
`xyz/dir_1/file4_dir1.txt' -> `target_dir/file4_dir1.txt'
cp: omitting directory `xyz/dir_2'
`xyz/dir_2/file1.txt' -> `target_dir/file1.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file2.txt' -> `target_dir/file2.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file3.txt' -> `target_dir/file3.txt'
`xyz/dir_2/file4.txt' -> `target_dir/file4.txt'


sent 414 bytes  received 134 bytes  1096.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: You should [never run a loop over `find` or `ls` results](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `for x in $(ls/find ...)` is strict no no. `ls/find | while read -r x` is slightly better & can possibly work for common use cases. But better way in this case is to use find's `-exec` option or use `find -print0 | while read -r -d '' x` loop.